# How far can I fall before it hurts?

Tags: steamworld-dig

I discovered by accident that if I am going back down my tunnels, and I just let myself fall straight down, sometimes it hurts me.

I assume there is some sort of limit to how far I can fall, but I am not sure what it is.

How far can I safely fall?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the beginning (before you find your uncle) area has different rules, it's 6/7 blocks

Here's the area I used to test it:

[image: Beginning area of SteamWorld Dig]

The platform with the sign with a skull and crossbones on it is where I let myself drop. That's 7 blocks high.

I also tried jumping off the side of it and took damage as well, but I'm not sure if the gravity is different after jumping. So unless that's different, it would be 6 blocks high.